# DocumentFilter for Two Decimal Points

Tags: java, swing

The DocumentFilter almost works as intended but my current issue is that if the user deletes two numerical characters and then enters one it shows the displayDoubleErrorMessage() and prevents/denies the user from entering anymore characters to finish the double up to two decimal places. Would the ideal situation be to show the error when the cell loses focus or stops editing and the value isn't a double? The intended purpose is to only allow the user to enter numerical characters and always show two decimal places.

Example: if the user enters 3, the cell will adjust to 3.00

I have tried multiple if else statements to check the StringBuilder to see if the value contained ., .0 and .00. There is an issue with that as the user would have to delete up to the last numerical character entered and repeat this process until the desired input.

I have tried JFormattedTextField with a mask formatter of ####.## but I don't like the leading zeroes if the user enters 3 or any other number that doesn't cover the enter mask. Example: 0003.00

```
 public static class DoubleDocumentFilter extends DocumentFilter
    {
    private JTable table;

    public DoubleDocumentFilter(JTable table)
    {
        this.table = table;
    }

    @Override
    public void insertString(FilterBypass fb, int offset, String value, AttributeSet attr)
        throws BadLocationException
    {
        Document document = fb.getDocument();

        String text = document.getText(0, document.getLength());
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.append(text.substring(0, offset));
        sb.append(value);
        sb.append(text.substring(offset));

        //ValidateDouble is regex that just validates a double to two decimal places
        if (new ValidateDouble().validate(sb.toString()))
        super.insertString(fb, offset, value, attr);
        else
        displayDoubleErrorMessage();
    }

    @Override
    public void replace(DocumentFilter.FilterBypass fb, int offset, int length, String value, AttributeSet attr)
        throws BadLocationException
    {
        Document document = fb.getDocument();

        String text = document.getText(0, document.getLength());
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.append(text.substring(0, offset));
        sb.append(value);
        sb.append(text.substring(offset));

        if (new ValidateDouble().validate(sb.toString()))
        super.replace(fb, offset, length, value, attr);
        else
        displayDoubleErrorMessage();
    }

    public void displayDoubleErrorMessage()
    {
        ErrorMessageModel errorModel = new ErrorMessageModel();

        errorModel.loadProperties();

        if (errorModel.isDisplayable("ProductDoubleDisplay")) {
        ErrorMessagePane pane = new ErrorMessagePane(table.getParent(),
            errorModel.getErrorMessage("ProductDouble"));
        if (pane.isCheckBoxSelected()) {
            errorModel.saveProperties("ProductDoubleDisplay", "false");
            errorModel.storeProperties();
        }
        }
    }
    }
```

Comment: Use a `JFormattedTextField` instead of creating a custom filter. See [How to Use Formatted Text Fields](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/formattedtextfield.html) for more information and examples.

Comment: I will try again to find a way to remove the leading zeros...Thank You Rob

Comment: DecimalFormat will solve my issue.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I ended up doing the cell editor.....

```
public class CurrencyCellEditor
    extends DefaultCellEditor
{
    private JFormattedTextField textField;

    private CSVFileController controller;

    private ProductTableModel tableModel;

    private int productRow;


    public CurrencyCellEditor(
        JFormattedTextField textField,
        CSVFileController controller,
        ProductTableModel tableModel)
    {
        super(textField);
        this.textField = textField;
        this.controller = controller;
        this.tableModel = tableModel;
        productRow = 0;
    }


    @Override
    public Component getTableCellEditorComponent(
        JTable table,
        Object value,
        boolean isSelected,
        int row,
        int column)
    {
        BigDecimal decimalValue = new BigDecimal(value.toString());
        DecimalFormat formatter = new DecimalFormat("$##,##0.00");
        this.productRow = row;

        textField.setFont(ApplicationStyles.TABLE_FONT);
        textField.addMouseListener(new TextFieldMouseAdapter());

        if (value != null)
        {
            decimalValue = decimalValue.setScale(2, BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_EVEN);
            formatter.setMinimumFractionDigits(2);
            formatter.setMinimumFractionDigits(2);
            textField.setText(formatter.format(value));
        }
        return textField;
    }


    @Override
    public Object getCellEditorValue()
    {
        if (!textField.getText().isEmpty())
        {
            if (textField.getText().toString().contains(",")
                || textField.getText().toString().contains("$"))
                return new BigDecimal(
                    textField.getText().toString().replaceAll("[,$]", ""));

            return new BigDecimal(textField.getText());
        }
        return new BigDecimal(0.00);
    }


    @Override
    public boolean stopCellEditing()
    {
        String value = textField.getText();

        Product product = tableModel.getProduct(productRow);

        if (value.contains(",") || value.contains("$"))
            value = value.replaceAll("[,$]", "");

        if (new ValidateDouble().validate(value))
        {
            controller.addProduct(product.getSupplier().getName(), product);
            return super.stopCellEditing();
        }

        ErrorMessageModel errorModel = new ErrorMessageModel();

        errorModel.loadProperties();

        if (errorModel.isDisplayable("ProductDoubleDisplay"))
        {
            ErrorMessagePane pane = new ErrorMessagePane(
                textField.getParent(),
                errorModel.getErrorMessage("ProductDouble"));
            if (pane.isCheckBoxSelected())
            {
                errorModel.saveProperties("ProductDoubleDisplay", "false");
                errorModel.storeProperties();
            }
        }
        return false;
    }


    private class TextFieldMouseAdapter
        extends MouseAdapter
    {
        @Override
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent evt)
        {
            if ((evt.getButton() == MouseEvent.BUTTON1)
                && evt.getClickCount() == 2)
                SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

                    @Override
                    public void run()
                    {
                        int offset = textField.viewToModel(evt.getPoint());
                        textField.setCaretPosition(offset);
                    }
                });
        }
    }
}
```